# How do I remove or stop a button in table view from working after registered amount of taps

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a button in a table view that adds rows. After a maximum of five rows I want to stop the user adding anymore.  Currently I show an alert after button recives 5 taps.

How can I  stop the user from using the button past this point?  Setting to hidden wont work as its a custom subclass and `property hidden` is not found on the class

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

[super viewDidLoad];

UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
titleLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
titleLabel.text = self.distributionBoard.dbRef;
titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0f];
[titleLabel sizeToFit];
self.navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel;

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneButtonPressed:)];

// Add new appliance button to the table view's footer view
UIView *footerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f, 0, 300.0f, 100.0f)];  
footerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
UIButton *newBoardButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];
CGRect buttonFrame = newBoardButton.frame;
buttonFrame.origin.x = footerView.frame.size.width - buttonFrame.size.width;
newBoardButton.frame = buttonFrame;
[newBoardButton addTarget:self action:@selector(addCircuitButtonPressed:)    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[footerView addSubview:newBoardButton];
self.tableView.tableFooterView = footerView;




}
```

.....

```
 ////limit to five appliances

 - (void)addCircuitButtonPressed:(id)sender {
LogCmd();
Circuit *circuit = [[ICCircuitManager manager] newCircuit];
circuit.distributionBoard = self.distributionBoard;
circuit.circuitReference = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [self.circuits count] + 1];
circuit.createdAt = [NSDate date];
circuit.modifiedAt = [NSDate date];
[self.distributionBoard addCircuitsObject:circuit];
[self loadData];
[self.tableView reloadData];

{
    m_buttonTouchCount++;
    if ( m_buttonTouchCount == 4)



    {
       UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"iCertifi"
                                                        message:@"Maximum number of appliances reached"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
       [alert show];
       // m_buttonTouchCount = 0; // reset to 0 here if required.
    }



  }
}
```

Comment: Which is custom subclass? newBoardButton? looks like it is UIButton in your code and should have hidden property for that.

Comment: Yep thats what I needed to do! I was trying to hide the wrong item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you have AlertView you can type this code to disable button:

```
[(UIButton *)sender setEnabled:NO];
```

or to hide button:

```
 [(UIButton *)sender setHidden:YES];
```

Comment: Thank very much for that, with a bracket removed after sender that worked a treat! `[(UIButton *)sender setHidden:YES];`